# Low Search: find channel entries with relationships to it?

Tags: channel-entries, search, low-search

I have a `Products` channel and an `Images` channel. The `Images` has a relationship field to `Products` (basically: a product can have 0 or more images).

Since most of my products do not have images, I'd like to showcase the products with images over the products without images. Meaning, I'd like to create a page that lists only the products that do have images, random order, and allow users to paginate through them.

**In Low Search, is there a way to get a list of products that have images?**

Products without images will still be viewable by doing a full text search or getting a list of entries based on the EE category they are associated with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that's currently possible, is to use a [SQL Parameter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#sql-params) to query the entry IDs that have a relationship. The other would be to create [a custom filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/create).

Comment: Thanks Low. Would it be something like this: `search:entry_id="SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles JOIN exp_relationships ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_relationships.child_id WHERE exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 4;"`? This doesn't seem to be working. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Try `entry_id=` rather than `search:entry_id=`.